# How to save all rows of a dynamic table in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to add the rows dynamically for one of the variables which is of type String array in my db. But it only saves the last value entered in the row rather than saving all of them in an array. Below is my view code:

```
<div class="row" ng-class='{red:true}'>
  <label for="remedy">Remedy</label>
</div>

<input name="remedy" id="remedy" ng-model="error.remedy" required>


<br/>
<div class="row" ng-class='{red:true}'>
  <a href="#!/errorcreate"  class="btn btn-primary btn-small" ng-click="addRemedyRow()" ng-class='{red:true}'>Add Row</a></div>
<br/>

<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th ng-class='{red:true}'>Remedy</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="rowContent in remedyrows">
  <td>{{rowContent.remedy}}</td>

  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
{{error.remedy}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
<a href="#!errorinput" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
```

And this is the code in javascript:

```
$scope.remedyrows = [];
$scope.addRemedyRow = function() {
  $scope.remedyrows.push({
    remedy: $scope.error.remedy
  });
```

Below is the output I am receiving (in a screenshot):

[image]

I added `dsdfg` as second row and my final `error.remedy` value just shows `dsdfg` rather than showing an array of both values : `[wdssdsd,dsdfg]`. `error` is the main document of which `remedy` is one of the fields of type `String` array.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: `{{remedyrows | json}}` instead of `{{error.remedy}}`?

Comment: `{{remedyrows | json}}` gives `[ { "remedy": "row1" }, { "remedy": "row2" } ]` as output.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov: I actually want this array fields to be attached to error document via `remedy` field. So I want final output as `["row1", "row2"]` instead of above given by `{{remedyrows | json}}`

Comment: Ok, at controller declare: `$scope.output = $scope.remedyrows.map(x => x.remedy)` and change to `{{output  | json}}`

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov: It works!! But how can I store it in my `error.remedy` to pass it in db? `$scope.error.remedy = $scope.output` won't store it in this format actually, right?

Comment: You should not store it exactly at `error.remedy` as it used for newly added `remedyrow`. Just use `output`: something like `$http({data: output, ....})`.

Comment: ok. let me try and rebuild my data based on these values. I have couple of more similar fields like this. Let me see how it shows up in my db. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov: Can you please provide this as an answer below so that I can mark it as accepted? Thanks again!

Comment: Pro tip: we like questions to be succinct here. There's no need to add how thankful you will be, or plead for people to "please help / please help me / please help me out". If you "tried many things", then please show us what they are - if you are wanting to show that you made a prior effort, then merely stating you did is unlikely to be believed. `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `error.remedy`, which is used as holder for future `remedyrow`, use intermediate variable `output` for displaying results and sending them to the server:

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.output = $scope.remedyrows.map(function(x) { return x.remedy; });
$http({data: $scope.output, method: 'POST', url: url});
```

**HTML:**

```
{{output | json}}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could have achieved it by following way:

```
 $scope.remedyrows = [];
    $scope.output;
    $scope.addRemedyRow = function() {
      $scope.remedyrows.push({
        remedy: $scope.error.remedy
      });
     $scope.output = $scope.remedyrows.toString();
    }
```

and in html

```
{{output}}
```

Comment: yeah. I didn't try it out actually. Just got out of ideas for a while trying to get `$scope.remedy` value.